# Display a table after reading in dimensions and table contents from a text file

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a project that displays a table after reading the contents and dimensions of the table from a text file.

The contents of puzzle.txt:

```
5 5
ferac
asdvb
mfkgt
opemd
welsr
```

I want my program to read the left number and store it in the variable numRow, and the right number in numCol, then read the letters into the puzzle array. However, when the dimension numbers print, they print as 0 0 instead of 5 5, and the puzzle array only outputs empty box characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
char puzzle [numRow][numCol];

void initializePuzzle() {

    string storeInput;
    int numRow, numCol;

    cout << "What is the name of the file?" << endl;
    getline(cin, storeInput);

    ifstream inFile (storeInput);
    inFile.open(storeInput.c_str());

    for (int c = 0; c < sizeof(storeInput); c++) {
        if (c == 0) {
            inFile >> numRow >> numCol;
            cout << numRow << ' ' << numCol << endl;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            inFile >> puzzle[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void displayPuzzle() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            cout << puzzle[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}

int main() {

    initializePuzzle();
    displayPuzzle();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never even check if that operation went well: `inFile.open(storeInput.c_str());` Not to mention that `ifstream inFile (storeInput);` already should open the file. Use [`std::ifstream::is_open()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/is_open) before you start reading.

Comment: Why do you have a loop that only does something on the first iteration?

Comment: I checked it, and the file is open

Answer (score 1):

You can do this just by using the *C++ Standard Library*. *Try this*: (See about [`std::copy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)...)

```
#include <iostream>  // For std::cout, std::endl, etc.
#include <fstream>   // For std::ifstream
#include <vector>    // For std::vector
#include <iterator>  // For std::ostream_iterator

int main() {
    std::string file_src;
    // Ask for file name...
    std::cout << "What is the name of the file? " << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, file_src);

    // Declare the file stream...
    std::fstream reader(file_src);
    // Terminate the program with value '1' in case of failure when reading file...
    if (reader.fail()) return 1;

    // Declaring necessary varibles...
    unsigned num_row, num_column;
    std::string temporary;

    /* Extracting 'num_row' and 'num_column' and declaring a 'std::vector' (which are
       better than dynamic arrays in numerous ways) with the dimensions... */
    reader >> num_row >> num_column;
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> puzzle(num_row, std::vector<char>(num_column));

    // Iterating over each line and copying the string where required...
    for (auto i = 0; std::getline(reader, temporary, '\n') && i < num_row; i++)
        if (!temporary.empty())
             std::copy(temporary.begin(), temporary.end(), puzzle[i].begin());
        else --i;

    // Close the stream...
    reader.close();

    // Print the resulting vector...
    for (auto & elem : puzzle) {
        std::copy(elem.begin(), elem.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> **Example:**
>
> **Input**:
>
> > puzzle.txt
>
> ---
>
> **Output**:
>
> > f e r a c
> >     a s d v b
> >     m f k g t
> >     o p e m d
> >     w e l s r

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this is a project for a class I'm taking and I'm required to use an array and other functions as well as the main function.